# How to run code section by section in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm new to RStudio (and to R as a whole to be fair) and I was wondering if there is a command or shortcut that would let me run the code in the console section by section.

I'm using 4 " - " to separate different chunks of my code. For example:

```
# ---- Item 3 ----
ols_reg <- lm(diff_mkt_share ~ ceu + canais + preco, 
           data = vec_data)
summary(reg1)

# ---- Item 6 ----
install.packages("AER")     # Pacote standard pra Ecoometria Aplicada em R

library("AER")
inst <- c(dados$z1, dados$z2)
cbind(vec_data, inst)

iv_reg <- ivreg(diff_mkt_share ~ ceu + canais + preco | ceu + canais + inst,
              data = vec_data)
summary(reg2)
```

Rstudio will let me easily hide Item 3 or Item 6 sections but is there a way (as there is one in MATLAB) such that I can run a full chunk of code with only a keystroke? Sure, I could press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> several times but it wouldn't be efficient for large chunks.

Comment: Highlight the section of code you want to run and press CTRL + R

Comment: Using menu "Code -> Run Region" could also help

Comment: Note that it is inadvisable to have `install.packages` in code that you are running frequently (especially on the same machine) since this will cause R to download the file and install it. Better to do it once outside of your code. You can update packages periodically using `update.packages`.

Comment: @lmo Thanks a lot for the tip. This is the code of an Applied Econometrics I'm taking right now and the Teaching Assistant is supposed to review our code and provide feedback. I wrote this line so it would install the package in whatever machine he runs it. Is there an easier and more adequate way of achieving the same result?

Comment: You can use `if(!require("AER")) {install.packages("AER"); library("AER")}` `require` loads the package if if is installed or returns FALSE if it is not installed. So, if it is not installed, `{install.packages("AER"); library("AER")}` installs the package and loads it.

Comment: Once more, thanks again! Nice solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [R Notebooks](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) in recent versions of RStudio. Then you can put your code in different chunks and run them as you please.

> An R Notebook is an R Markdown document with chunks that can be executed independently and interactively, with output visible immediately beneath the input.

If you must use an R script, I usually just highlight the multiple lines of code I want to run at once and do a `Cmd + Enter` or `Ctrl + r`, depending on what OS I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

See: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts
"Run the current code section"

And for defining code sections, see: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE/#code-sections

Answer (score 1):

In the RStudio source pane, you can run the current section ("chunk") of an R script by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. No need for Notebooks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Mac OS. I've tried Shift + option + T and Sift + command + T and nothing happens :/

Comment: @RaulGuarini Cmd+Option+T? See https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: For me the correct shortcut is `ctrl+alt+T` as indicated in @gaspar's answer (on a mac:  `Cmd+Option+T`)

Comment: Works on linux desktops.

Answer (score 0):

I utilize the shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key to run the current code chunk in RMarkdown, w/o selecting any lines to run.
For more shortcut methods: check out the [R Studio Cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score -3):

Simply enclose it in brackets:  {  all contiguous lines of code }

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked, about how to *run* code chunks.